# using extension for enum in a easier way

Tags: c#

I m trying to make a extension for enums.

```cs
public enum Cars {
   Chevrolet,
   Corvette,
   Lambo
}

public static T[] ToEnumArray<T>(this T type)
{
    return (T[])Enum.GetValues(type.GetType());
}

===============================
   this part will not work
===============================

var data = Cars.ToEnumArray();

===============================

foreach(var _result in data) {
   Console.WriteLine(_result);
}
```

well I know that I could use `ToEnumArray<Cars>()`
but isnt this way possible? by just doing `Cars.ToEnumArray()`

**how it would work but without extension**

```cs
public static T[] ToEnumArray<T>()
{
   return (T[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));
}

Cars[] cars = ToEnumArray<Cars>();
```

Comment: There are no static extension methods.

Comment: @Sweeper Extensions need to be static :)

Comment: How about "extension methods must be called like instance methods, or like a static method on the enclosing type"? You can't "extend" a type.

Comment: I don't see the point of using extension methods for this case.

Comment: `Enum.GetValues<SomeType>()` its already built for you, however not in the semantics you would like

Comment: @SᴇM the point is that its easier to use and way better then using Enum.GetValues

Comment: @TheGeneral Enum.GetValues does not have a typearegument

Comment: @lara2002 sure it does https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues?view=net-5.0#System_Enum_GetValues__1 depending on framework and version you are using

Comment: @lara2002 I don't think it's "easier" to use or "way better", what you mean by that? If you want to get an array from enums that way, create a static class, with your extension method, but this time it's not an extension method.

Comment: @TheGeneral .NET 5.0 only

Comment: @lara2002 is there any other version ? (rhetorical)  :)

Comment: @SᴇM `Enum.ToEnumArray()` is better usable then `StaticClass.Method<Enum>()`

Comment: @TheGeneral I m using .NET Framework and not .NET Core :)

Answer (score 2):

There are only two ways to call an extension method. You either call it like a regular static method declared in a static class, or you call it like an instance method ([extension method invocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#extension-methods)).

[Language Spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#extension-methods) says:

> An extension method is a regular static method. In addition, where its enclosing static class is in scope, an extension method can be invoked using instance method invocation syntax, using the receiver expression as the first argument.

You can't call it on a type in which it is not declared, like `Cars`.

My suggestion is that you declare a regular static method:

```
static class UtilityClass {
    public static T[] ToEnumArray<T>() where T: Enum
    {
       return (T[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

And if you don't like writing the prefix `UtilityClass.` all the time, use a `using static` directive:

```
using static SomeNamespace.UtilityClass;

...

Cars[] cars = ToEnumArray<Cars>();
```

Comment: And if you dont like typing at all, you can prefix all your methods with an underscore and a number `public static T[] _1<T>()` FTW :) oh and +1 for a good post

Comment: I suggest adding `where T : Enum` constraint for `ToEnumArray<T>` method